why i can't update date format in wordpress?
i am using wordpress, and publisher theme newspaper ;
I have a strange problem, I want to change the format of the date in WordPress, I go to
Settings, I change the date but still the same format no changing,
I have added code in functions.php   to change the format; not working
I update the date from the database, it's changed in the panel but when view the post the format is not changed,
i disable the theme and use simple wordpress theme
screenshot of the problem 
i try to change the date format from the settings , not work
i try to add snipet code php in functions.php don't work too

You can go through below steps
Theme Compatibility:
Some themes might override the default WordPress date settings. Check if your theme has its own settings for date formats. You can look for these settings in the Theme Options or Customizer.
Cache Issues:
If you have a caching plugin installed, the old date format might be cached. Clear your website cache and your browser cache to see if the new format appears.
Incorrect Settings:
Ensure you are updating the date format in the correct location. The settings should be updated in the WordPress dashboard under Settings > General > Date Format.
Plugin Conflicts:
Some plugins might interfere with the date format settings. Deactivate all plugins and check if the issue persists. If the date format updates correctly after deactivating the plugins, reactivate them one by one to identify the conflicting plugin.
Hardcoded Date Formats:
In some cases, the date format might be hardcoded in the theme or plugin files. You might need to edit the PHP files directly. Look for the_date(), the_time(), or similar functions in your theme's template files.
Locale Settings:
The date format might be affected by yourstrong text** site's locale settings. Ensure that the locale settings in Settings > General > Site Language are set correctly.
Custom Code:
If you or a developer have added custom code to your theme or a child theme, it might be overriding the default date format. Check the theme’s functions.php file or any custom plugin for such code.**

Thank you for your response, I installed a new blank WordPress site, which uses the default twenty twenty four theme, I use no plugin, but the problem is still the same when I modify the date format in Wordpress settings, the date doesn't change, I even tried a code on functions.php, but it doesn't change I'll send you the code to see
function custom_date_format($date_format){
return 'j F Y';
}
add_filter('date_format','custom_date_format');

Thanks for your answer ,i wolve 50% of the problem but still the 50 %, i add filter to change the date format , it's work on post single page , but in my home page still without changes , i think it's problem og themes settings , but i can't find where search , i haven't find
screen shot of the problem
